# Suppose $h:S^1 \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic, and $f:S^1 \to S^1$ defined by $f(x)=-x$ Then $f\circ h$ is nullhomotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $h:S^1 \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic, and $f:S^1 \to S^1$ defined by $f(x)=-x$ Then $f\circ h$ is nullhomotopic.

I've seen this in a proof, And  I want  to convince  myself by coming up with an  explicit homotopy but I am struggling. Any help?

Take Say $H:S^1\times I \to S^1$ to be the Homotopy between $h$ and the constant function $c$. with
$$H(s,0)=h(s) $$
$$H(s,1)=c$$
I need to define a homotopy $F:S^1\times I \to S^1$ most likely in terns of $H(x,t)$ between $f \circ h$ and $c$.

Comment: If $h$ is nullhomotopic, then $f\circ h$ is nullhomotopic for *any* map $f\colon S^1\to S^1$. You have it set up precisely correctly, except the homotopy will be between $f\circ h$ and $f(c)$, not $c$. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: @TedShifrin,  I see.., the mistake I made in all my attempt was to think that the homotopy will be between $f\circ h$ and $c$. if it is as you said between $f\circ h$ and $f(c)$ then I could for instance define $F(s,t)=f(H(s,t))$ and that should work I believe. But intuitively, why is it $f(c)$ instead of $c$

Comment: Why should it be $c$? It *needs* to be wherever $f$ sends the constant, since you're applying $f$ to the homotopy. I mean, if you insist on $c$, you can do the proof you now have and then join $f(c)$ to $c$ with a path [making your interval no longer $[0,1]$ but $[0,2]$, say].

Comment: Oh okay.I think it's clear now. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic via $H$, then $k \circ f$ and $k\circ g$ are homotopic via $k\circ H$.

Given that $h: S^1 \to S^1$ is nulhomotopic, let $H$ be the homotopy between $h$ and the constant map $g(x) = c \ \ \forall x \in S^1$ for some $c \in S^1$.

Now, $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is defined as $f(x) = -x$, then, $f \circ H$ is a homotopy between $f\circ h$ and $f \circ g$. But, since $g$ is constant map, so is $f\circ g$. Thus, $f\circ H = -H$ serves as the required homotopy between $f\circ h$ and constant map $f \circ g$.